# JIRA Plugin that Creates ServiceNow ticket

Tags: web-services, jira, jira-plugin, servicenow

I was wondering if there was a plugin available that would listen to changes to a JIRA ticket such as Build Requests set to Staging and from there create a ticket within ServiceNow. If there is no plugin available for this, could someone point me in the right direction to get this project going?

Answer (score 1):

there is no ready-to-use plugin available for that use case.
We created our own plugin for that but unfortunately this plugin is not available for the public.
On top of that it would be very complicated to create a plugin which could be used by everybody because you would need a huge amount of configuration options.

I think you will have to contact a consultant to create your own plugin for your desired use-cases.

Comment: can you provide just a bit more detail on how I would be able to get a head start on development of this plugin? or email raphaelokere@hotmail